# Are this 2 code parts same?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Snippets:

```
 private double memberVal;   
 public double MemberVal   
 {   
  get { return memberVal; }   
  set { memberVal= value; }   
 }
```

and

```
public double MemberVal   
 {    
  get; set;  
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but now they are the same

```
private double memberVal;
public double MemberVal
{
    get { return memberVal; }
    set { memberVal= value; }
}
```

and

```
public double MemberVal
{
get; set;
}
```

**Update**
Except - as pointed out by Johannes Rössel - that you can access the field from code in the first case but not in the latter :-) –

Meaning that in the first code sample, within your class you can directly set the backing member for the property (i.e. `private double memberVal1` e.g. `memberVal = 1.1;`), where in the second, there is still a private backing member for the property, but it's now invisible.
You can only access it through the property.

Comment: Except that you can access the field from code in the first case but not in the latter :-)

Comment: Except for the inaccessible, auto-generated private member in the second example.

Comment: There was mistake. MemberVal is public.

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: Yes, that's well worth pointing out, have updated to include same :)

Answer (score 13):

Almost. In the second example, `MemberVal` is not publicly accessible.

Comment: it was mistake. MemberVal is public.

Comment: @Samvel - Based on your edit, they are now the same. The first snippet will use one more variable than the second snippet, but the behavior is the same.

Comment: "The first snippet will use one more variable than the second snippet" . . . ish . . . The class still have a private storage member for the property, it's autogenerated and invisible but can be seen through refelection and/or in IL.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that code is equivalent, apart from MemberVal not being public in the second example (did you mean that). In the latter case, the compiler generates a field for you. It will have another, auto-generated name.

Answer (score 0):

```
private double memberVal;
public double MemberVal
{
    get { return memberVal; }
    set { memberVal= value; }
} 

public double MemberVal
{
    get; set;
}
```

second of the code-snippets is not supposed work on .net 2.0, coz it was introduced in .net 3.0.

The second is the short-hand notation for the first one but works only on .net 3.0 or higher.